# How to hide "Attachment" menu for specific model and group in Odoo?

Tags: object, odoo, hide, attachment

I want to hide "Attachment(s)" menu in the form view for specific group and model/object in odoo 8. How can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

I do not have idea about hide attachment menu but can restrict to attach via this js code:

```
odoo.define('module_name', function(require) {
    "use strict";

    var core = require('web.core');
    var data = require('web.data');
    var framework = require('web.framework');
    var sideWidget = require('web.Sidebar');
    var Model = require('web.Model');
    var Dialog = require('web.Dialog');
    var _t = core._t;
    var QWeb = core.qweb;


    var sidebar = sideWidget.include({


        redraw: function() {

            var self = this;
            this._super.apply(this, arguments);
            if (this.getParent()) {
                var view = this.getParent();



                if (this.getParent().dataset.model != "there which model you do not want attach files") {
                    this.$('.o_sidebar_add_attachment .o_form_binary_form').change(this.on_attachment_changed);                               
                }
            }
        },

         });


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <data>
        <template id="assets_backend_niwe" name="alfresco_odoo assets" inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
            <xpath expr="." position="inside">

                <script type="text/javascript" src="file location"/>


            </xpath>
        </template>
    </data>

</odoo>
```

Save it separate file and add this js file it to assets backend.